# How to get value of columns and put it into label C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm working on a Grade Management System. I'll just ask how do I get all the data of columns and put it into selected Labels and save it to new database

If there's another way or advice I'll be thankful - I'm just new here.

This is my code

```
string sql = "select distinct * from tbl_TestGrade where ID = '" + textBox1 .Text+ "' ";

cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);

dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    // I want to get all the data of the student subjects by id 
}

dr.Close();
```

Comment: Are you want only get data of columns from SQL? You can get data by using `dr.GetValues(index);` and if you want to put it into the label, you can use code like this: `label1.Text = dr.GetString(index);`

Comment: What do you mean by selected labels? Usually you would display one value per label. How many values do you expect to retrieve from the database?

Comment: What do you mean by "labels"? Do you mean column? Also, your first line is vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of specific column with the DataReader.Item[string columnName] property. Try storing the data in a list while looping through the reader.

```
List<object> studentData = new List<object>();    

while(dr.Read())
{
    studentData.Add(dr.Item["Subjects"]);
}
```